# Why can't I mark duplicate questions which are downvoted/not answered?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

A user asked the same question 4 times and get downvotes for different things (low quality, off-topic, etc.). Now he created a new account (I think so, because the question seems to be the same). So I tried to mark it as duplicate but I can't because of: **This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer**. Afaik the policy of Stack Exchange is to conform the question instead to create a new one.

Is there a reason not to be able to mark a question as duplicate if it is from another user and downvoted / not answered?

I'm refering to:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969820/arduino-program-not-working-propoerly
- [Arduino Program Stop Working after 1 sec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031731/arduino-program-stop-working-after-1-sec)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033739/aruino-program-doesnt-work-after-1sec
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039421/arduino-program-stops-working-after-1-sec (with new account)

Comment: I just looked, and someone's upvoted the answer on your second linked question. So you should be able to mark the one from a new account to that, the others as well.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux

Comment: Official policy is that it is acceptable for *different users* to continue asking the same question over and over again, as long as it has not been answered. I've gone on record as vehemently disagreeing with this policy, but alas it has not changed.

Comment: @CodyGray If it's worded slightly differently I don't see an issue with it.  When the question is finally answered the other versions can be closed as duplicates and there will be more search terms available for people to find the question.  Old unanswered questions don't typically get answered.  New questions (even if they are duplicates) have a better shot at being answered.

Comment: The reason behind this is that closing as duplicates is so that the answer is in just one place, not so much because the questions are identical. But using sockpuppets like this is abusive behavior. I think you should flag for a moderator as Servy said because moderators are not subject to this limitation.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi, lol you got me. Marking my question about duplicate qiestions as duplicate...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Is there a reason not to be able to mark a question as duplicate if it is from another user and downvoted / not answered?

Yes, it's there so that people aren't told that they won't get an answer because someone else didn't get an answer.  The only exception to this is a single person asking the same question over and over again.

You can flag the post for moderator attention claiming that the user is posting a duplicate question through multiple accounts.  They can close the question even if the duplicate has no answer, and possibly even take further action as a result of this abusive behavior.