# Better to reduplicate, or to edit, a poorly worded question with no good answers?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I have a meta-SO question that has been asked twice already by other users (namely, a feature request to be able to use anchors to link to specific points within a question or answer). Note the feature is something I want on SO, but this feature request I'd like to discuss on meta. So I suppose this is a meta-meta question.

The problem is [the second](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303420/is-it-possible-to-add-html-anchor-in-a-stackoverflow-answer) iteration was marked as a dupe of [the first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290870/fragment-identifiers-on-headings-within-answers), and neither question is very well written, and neither has an accepted answer (and for good reason, IMO). In the second iteration, the title is clear and brings search engines into SO. Alas, it has 5 downvotes, which are likely deserved based on the poor quality of the (non title part of the) question.

I think this feature would be really helpful and want to discuss the topic more, so what should I do? Since the question is old, and has not attracted any new attention, there is a good chance it will just go unanswered or unaddressed. Should I start a new question or just edit the original? One problem with an edit is I wouldn't be able to accept an answer, but perhaps the OP would do it.

One option I'm considering is asking a minor variant as a new question: right now the two questions only ask to the feature under question in *answers*; I'd like to see this feature added for *questions* too. Frankly, I don't think that's enough novelty to count as a new question, so it would basically be gaming the system to get around being marked as a dupe. Which I'd rather not do.

A final option would be for mods to delete both questions and start fresh, with a better question. I'm just throwing ideas against the wall to see what you all think, as I realize that is probably a Bad Idea.

Note this seems subtly different than the [closely related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312172/offer-a-bounty-and-add-details-to-a-question) as to whether to add a bounty to an old question, or ask a new question, at SO. My question is about what to do at meta-SO where there are no bounties, and the standards are (presumably) a little different. It seems there are very closely related, not duplicates. But there is information there that is useful for answering my question.

---

**My best guess at the answer**

I should simply **ask a new question**. Check out the fine print below those questions marked as duplicates:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If
>   those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new
>   question.

This is a bit ambiguous though, as it says to ask a "new question" which could refer to a new instance of the same question (i.e., a dupe), or a completely new question that is not simply a duplicate of the present question.

The most obvious interpretation is to make an entirely new question. But then we can look at the comments on [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267217/why-cant-i-mark-duplicate-questions-which-are-downvoted-not-answered), which suggest that as long as I'm not the OP of one of the questions, it's OK to start a new question even it is 100% duplicate. For instance:

> Official policy is that it is acceptable for different users to
>   continue asking the same question over and over again, as long as it
>   has not been answered. I've gone on record as vehemently disagreeing
>   with this policy, but alas it has not changed.

But that is also ambiguous: my question has an answer, but not an *accepted* answer. We also have this:

> When the question is finally answered the other versions can be closed
>   as duplicates and there will be more search terms available for people
>   to find the question. Old unanswered questions don't typically get
>   answered. New questions (even if they are duplicates) have a better
>   shot at being answered.

So basically, as long as you are not one of the OPs spamming the site, it is ok to ask the same question if the current question/answers don't satisfy your needs? Then if yours is answered (accepted?), and it is a dupe, then the *others* can be marked as dupes retroactively? This frankly seems the most promising option for my case.

---

**Update** -- I asked the question, and it was closed as a duplicate. So now I'm confused.

[Feature request: Add a link within a question or answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312498/add-a-link-within-a-question-or-answer)

Comment: Well right now the only way to go is to wait for a response to your comment that you posted not too long before creating this meta.

Comment: @Gimby : or both. Even if my comments get answered there, a good answer to this meta-question could still be useful if the situation happens again. I believe this meta-question has broader application than that particular first-order question.

Comment: Are you referring to meta questions specifically (like your examples) or all sites?  I think the distiction is important as my opinion is going to be different on Meta and on Main sites

Comment: @psubsee2003 I am referring to meta only, good point. The feature request stuff is all meta, but I want the feature to be included in SO. I have clarified in the OP.

Comment: Commenting at old threads is sort of useless. This is a recursive comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that it was a feature request that was recently ignored, not a discussion or support question, makes it a mistake to re-ask. Feature requests have a unique quality that the OP did not seem to appreciate when posting.

Even assuming the answers weren't very good, for arguments' sake, the fact that the request at the original was not upvoted significantly means that there is not support for the idea. If you must, open it as a topic for *discussion* to get clarification on why people don't think it is a good idea. There is no guarantee it won't be closed as a duplicate, but your chances are better.

Hence, DO NOT take the advice at the putative duplicate, to ask again. With a feature request, it is a mistake to request it again if it has been seen (even without a good answer), not upvoted, and the developers haven't acted on it. It pretty much amounts to spam.

As a commenter succinctly put it in a follow up to all this:

> Hmm, no, no amount of discussion is going to make an SE programmer
>   implement this feature. It was requested before and ignored, you can't
>   always get what you want.